# sharedApplication is unavailable: not available in ios app extension - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I want solutions to overcome this error.

I am getting an error while I'm compiling and building up my iOS project. I got an error in `IQKeyboardManager` at this place:

```
UIWindow *originalKeyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

and one another place where I got this error is also the same:

```
CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
```

Can anyone have solutions? Please give me...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
UIWindow * originalKeyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window];
```

And swift

```
let originalKeyWindow: UIWindow? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!
```

Comment: i m getting this error : initializing 'CGRect' (aka CGRect) with an expression of incompatible type UIWindow * _Nullable'.

Comment: Change CGRect  to GCRectMake